# Running reports at scheduled times and emailing them using Oracle SQL Developer/Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to use SQL Developer to automate reports at a scheduled time and then email those reports even when the SQL Developer is closed? How would I go about it?

I noticed that there is a scheduler for the Developer but that is for "Jobs" and not as much for scheduling Reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in `SQL Developer`, write it in Java, and start the Java process as a background process.

(or)

You can schedule the Java command for your program using O/S schedule commands. Your program will be invoked according to the schedule. Then connect to database, generate a report and send an email in your program.